# Getting error in visual studion whenver i publish

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I formatted my system recently and installed windows 7. so i installed all software again. when after i installed VS it is working fine only. but when i am build / publish it is showing an error. how to resolve this issue?

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Is i have to install something ah? please instruct me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the "System.Web.WebPages" dll is available in the solution/project references. If not add it (the required version). clean solution, build again. Publish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: right click on references => Add => reference => search for the dll and add and follow the procedure.

I am assuming you are using VS 2010 or less.